# How to set/ change orientation for mat2image conversion

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I am using spm write vol function to convert mat to .img. 
Would you let me know how to set/change the orientation of image (i would like to set axial orientation).  I tried following one but not working,

```
header.hist.orient=0;
```

Comment: I have problems understanding your question. Is this about rotating or using a different coordinate system? What is `header.hist`? Maybe put the code you already got into your question.

Comment: That doesnt seem like Matlab code... and its just a single line!

Comment: How to use spm_write_vol () to save mat file in analyze format? where I also can change Planar Orientation  (sagittal/coronal/ transverse) as suggested in ANALYZE 7.5 File Format ,